# Scala api wrapper syntax

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Suppose I'm trying to wrap an api which a wrapper object foo.

I want to do foo.get.endpoint

is there an nice way to express this? Currently I have

```
object foo {

  object get {
    val method = HttpMethods.GET
    def endpoint = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(stuff)
  }
}
```

Is there good way to abstract the stuff so I can easy define endpoints then make the request elsewhere so I can define

```
def endpoint = "endpoint/foo/blah?morestuff=1"
```

and have foo.get.endpoint still make the request

Comment: I don't know what question you're asking, specifically. In it's current form it's too open ended and opinion based to return a reasonable answer. Can you refine your question?

Comment: I think the retrofit library does that